# Add a meaningful description for the link to answers in review queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was trying to go to an answer directly from review queues, and found out that we've the following:

> [image]

---

Of course there's a meaningful tooltip:

> [image]

Why can't we have a meaningful description like *View answer* ..?

---

**UPDATE:**

This is applies to questions as well:

> [image]